# How to change text color of a tag in TextField Flutter

Tags: flutter, textformfield

I'm working on a social media app in Flutter. I'm implementing the comments functionality. When I write a word in comments textfield with "@", it searches the users from firebase cloud firestore. Now, what I want is that when I click on the user tile, the username will append to the textfield in a bold font while other text remain normal. I there a way to achieve this in TextFormField or TextField?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding HTML to it

something like this

```
String complete = "Hello this is @" +"<b>" + someName+ "</b> ";
```

you need to add this in onChange listener and detect '@'